# Can't write different items in different columns in a csv file

Tags: php, csv, curl, dom, web-scraping

I've written a script in `php` to scrape different `title` of posts and its `links` and write them to a csv file from a webpage. I wish to write `titles` in `column A` and its associated `links` in `column B`. The script does the job when I write them in a single column. However, as I don't know how to write data in multiple columns, I got stuck.

Currently it is writing the `titles` in a csv file as I've already commented out the `links` portion within the script only because I don't know how to write them in `column B`. Any help to solve the problem will be appreciated.

This is what I've tried with:

```
<?php
    include "simple_html_dom.php";
    $url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping";
    function get_information($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $dom = new simple_html_dom();
        $dom->load($htmlContent);
        $links = array();
        $file = fopen("outputfile.csv","w");
        foreach ($dom->find('.question-hyperlink') as $link) {
            fputcsv($file,array($link->innertext));
            //fputcsv($file,array($link->href));
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    get_information($url);
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> try this code

```
<?php
    include "simple_html_dom.php";
    $url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-scraping";
    function get_information($url)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER, 1);
        $htmlContent = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);
        $dom = new simple_html_dom();
        $dom->load($htmlContent);
        $links = array();
        $file = fopen("outputfile.csv","w");
        foreach ($dom->find('.question-hyperlink') as $link) {
            fputcsv($file,[$link->innertext,$link->href]);
        }
        fclose($file);
    }
    get_information($url);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please add some explanation of your code? So that OP can understand in better way.

Comment: Thanks @Jignesh Joisar, for your solution. It worked perfectly. Btw, how to strip a string in `php` to kick out unwanted space?

Comment: @asmitu use trim() and str_replace() function remove unwanted space